# How to add a prefix or folders in a bucket for multiple source for Canvas LMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, canvas-lms

I have found out how to store files from local to an Amazon S3 Bucket
but I have other problems.

In my bucket when I upload a file from my Canvas LMS website to the S3 bucket the files stored at

```
s3://Mybucket/account_1/attachemenst/myfile.pdf
```

but I have three "folders" in my bucket:

```
s3://Mybucket/AAA/
s3://Mybucket/BBB/
s3://Mybucket/CCC/
```

and I need to configure the yml files to tell every image where to save its files

```
www.AAA.com => [save files at ]=> s3://Mybucket/AAA/
www.BBB.com => [save files at ]=> s3://Mybucket/BBB/
```

And so on.

I use docker do build images, how can I do it? Should I change the bucket name in `amazon_s3.yml` from

```
bucket_name: Mybucket
```

to

```
bucket_name: Mybucket/AAA
```

I tried it, but nothing happens just errors.

---

UPDATE:

I know how to add it in file_store.yml
so I use this configuration to save files from CANVAS LMS to dir-A directory :

```
development:
   storage: s3
   path_prefix: attachments/dir-A/
```

what I need it's to change this path_prefix for every docker-compose to tell every organization where to save files in aws s3
for example :

```
Organization A =>  s3://bucket-name/account_1/attachments/dir-A/  
Organization B =>  s3://bucket-name/account_1/attachments/dir-B/  
Organization C =>  s3://bucket-name/account_1/attachments/dir-C/
```

So like I said above, I know how to save files in directory ,but I used by Dockerfile by building images with amazon_s3.yml and file_store.yml

And now I need to change just the path_prefix for every organization
is that possible and how please?

Comment: I have no idea about Canvas-LMS, but from some example configs on Github I can see that other storage backends support a `path_prefix` configuration variable, maybe that's also available for S3? Otherwise you'll have to go with separate buckets, or maybe S3- Access Points.

Comment: Thank you, Mr @Maurice, for correct my post firstable, yeah I read something like prefix, but I don't find how to do it exactly I will be continuous my search and waiting for some help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution;
So to make edit path_prefix in file_store.yml for every docker-compose

I add this ENV

```
production:
  storage: s3
  path_prefix: attachments/<%= ENV['HELLO_VARIABLE'] %>/
```

and in docker-compose.yml I add HELLO_VARIABLE to environment like:

```
  app: &app
    image: registry/images:1
    environment:
      - HELLO_VARIABLE=dir-A
```

and work perfectly when I upload now file to my canvas LMS platform
the files stored at

```
https://mybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/account_1/attachments/dir-A/1/myFile.jpg
```